# Missing dependencies with Atmosphere and Jersey

Tags: dependencies, jersey, atmosphere

I am trying Atmosphere together with Jersey to be able to broadcast messages to users. However on request to the Jersey endpoint, the following appears in the log and results in ServletException.

```
SEVERE: The following errors and warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes:
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.JSONProvider.setMessageContext(org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.MessageContext) at parameter at index 7
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for field: private org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.MessageContext org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.RequestDispatcherProvider.mc
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.JAXBElementProvider.setMessageContext(org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.MessageContext) at parameter at index 1
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for field: private org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.MessageContext org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.MultipartProvider.mc
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.JAXBElementProvider.setMessageContext(org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.MessageContext) at parameter at index 13
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for field: private org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.MessageContext org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.FormEncodingProvider.mc
```

Part of stacktrace:

```
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet AtmosphereServlet
javax.servlet.ServletException
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.init(AtmosphereServlet.java:540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1173)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:809)
```

I am using Maven and have added the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
  <artifactId>atmosphere-jersey</artifactId>
  <version>0.6.3</version>
</dependency>
```

What am I missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was apparently that two implementations of JAX-RS somehow existed in the application. This can be solved by making Jersey scan only the package containing the Rest classes and therefore be unaware of other JAX-RS implementations.

```
<servlet>
  <description>AtmosphereServlet</description>
  <servlet-name>AtmosphereServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet</servlet-class>
   ...
  <init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</ param-name> 
    <param-value>mypackage.with.the.rest.classes</param-value>
  </init-param>
</servlet>
```

Thanks to Paul Sandoz on the Jersey mailing list and Jeanfrancois on the Atmosphere mailing list.

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly in my case while Apache Tomcat was telling me "SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.RequestDispatcherProvider.setMessageContext(org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.MessageContext) at parameter at index 14" Just changed mypackage.with.the.rest.classes for the package where my REST was defined, and everything worked. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It was reported that downgrading a web-app descriptor version in web.xml can help disable the native (Jersey) scanning:  http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-deployment.html#JAX-RSDeployment-WebLogic

```
<!-- From: -->
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
</web-app>
<!-- To: -->
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
</web-app>
```